# How to find Apriori association in T-SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, apriori

Database:

```
Transaction  ProductID
 1              1000
 2              1000
 2              1001 
 3              1000
 3              1002
 4              1000
 4              1001
 5              1003
```

In the above table, how to find this result with a T-SQL statement?

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
| PRODUCTID1  | PRODUCTID2|     SUPPORT     |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1000   |   1001    |         2       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1000   |   1002    |         1       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1000   |   1003    |         0       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1001   |   1002    |         0       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1001   |   1003    |         0       |
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
|      1002   |   1003    |         0       |,
+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Test Table:

```
create table transactions(
   ORDERID    INT,
   PRODUCTID INT
);

insert into transactions(ORDERID, PRODUCTID)
values ('1', '1000')
      ,('2', '1000')
      ,('2', '1001')
      ,('3', '1000')
      ,('3', '1002')
      ,('4', '1000')
      ,('4', '1001'),
       ('5', '1003');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @marc_s: Apriori is the name of the algorithm OP wants to use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you infer the zeros? i.e. can we just say that anything not listed is zero? if so:

```
select t1.PRODUCTID as [PRODUCTID1], t2.PRODUCTID as [PRODUCTID2],
       COUNT(1) as [SUPPORT]
from transactions t1 inner join transactions t2
  on t1.ORDERID = t2.ORDERID
  and t1.PRODUCTID < t2.PRODUCTID
group by t1.PRODUCTID, t2.PRODUCTID
```

With output:

```
PRODUCTID1  PRODUCTID2  SUPPORT
----------- ----------- -----------
1000        1001        2
1000        1002        1
```

Comment: i wonder one more thing. how to find 3's combination of this. according to your result (for first row); {1000,1001,1002 } and {1000,1001,1003}

Comment: @wide - you could try whacking in a second join using the same pattern - but it starts to get messy. Really you'd need to give specific data examples to check the result (there are no transactions spanning the 3 at the moment)

Comment: yes,but sample dataset likes my big database structure.And my database contains 2,3,4 products which sold together. i don't know how to do this. i'm implementing Apriori algorithm.